# CodeIgniter Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'. Inserting images names in a column using implode

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Please, I am moving multiple images to a destination folder and I insert the images name in a single column separated by a comma. This means, all other records will be inserted into a row once and the names of the images will be inserted in a column separated by a comma. Moving of the images worked fine from the file upload but the data is not inserted into the database. It is giving this error below :

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 1465

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

INSERT INTO `wzb_product` (`WZB_ProductCode`, `ProductGrade`, `WZB_ProductName`, `WZB_ProductDescription`, `WZB_QuantityPerUnit`, `WZB_UnitPrice`, `WZB_ProductOwner`, `WZB_CategoryName`, `WZB_VerifiedByAgent`, `ProductPhotoName`, `Addedby`) VALUES ('PR02_893', 'OLD', 'Giovani Vialli Shoe', Array, NULL, '350000', 'Admin', 'Bag And Shoe', 'NO', 'main-product01.jpg,main-product02.jpg,main-product03.jpg,main-product04.jpg', '')

The fact is I do not have a column named Array. The form uses TinyMCE to allow the user type Product Description. I suspect the images file names to be the culprit, or could it be the TinyMCE column(ProducrDescription)?

This is my Controller method that does it :

```
$filesCount = count($_FILES['productphotos']['name']); 
        for($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++)
        {               
            $_FILES['file']['name'] = $_FILES['productphotos']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['type'] = $_FILES['productphotos']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['productphotos']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['error'] = $_FILES['productphotos']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['file']['size'] = $_FILES['productphotos']['size'][$i];

            $testprodpath = './Products/Old/BagShoes/';
            //$uploadPath = './Products/';
            //$uploadPath = base_url().'Products/';
            $config['upload_path'] = $testprodpath;
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
            $config['max_size']    = '5000';    // max_size in kb
            $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['productphotos']['name'][$i];

            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            //load upload library
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);                

            //upload the files
            if($this->upload->do_upload('file'))
            {
               //Get data about the files
                $fileData = $this->upload->data();
                $name_array[] = $fileData['file_name'];
                           } // closes if

            else
            {
              echo $this->upload->display_errors();             
            } //closes else
        }  //closes for loop 

                $content = $this->input->post('content');
                $datatiny['content'] = $content;

                $imagesnames= implode(',', $name_array);

                //Insert file information into the database
           $data2 = array(
              'WZB_ProductCode'=>$this->input->post('productcode'),
              'ProductGrade'=>$this->input->post('productgrade'),
              'WZB_ProductName'=>$this->input->post('productname'),
              'WZB_ProductDescription'=>$datatiny,
              'WZB_QuantityPerUnit'=>$this->input->post('quantityperunity'),
              'WZB_UnitPrice'=>$this->input->post('unitprice'),
              'WZB_ProductOwner'=>$this->input->post('productowner'),
              'WZB_CategoryName'=>$this->input->post('productcategory'),
              'WZB_VerifiedByAgent'=>$this->input->post('verifiedbyagent'),                  
              'ProductPhotoName'=>$imagesnames,
              'Addedby'=>$this->input->post('addedby')
            );

           $this->db->insert('wzb_product', $data2);                       
           $this->session->set_flashdata('Added Successfully','Record  successfully added'); 
     }   //closes if for checking if file input has file is submitted and if file is uploaded
```

I am not using model. The point is if I insert a single image name that is not multiple images. It works fine by moving the image name and also insert records into the database with the image file name but I am getting this error when it is multiple images.

I appreciate all the efforts in advance.

Regards,

Comment: print the query and put it in mysql and check error.

Answer (score 0):

You have description in `$datatiny['content']` and you are using `$datatiny` in initialisation. It is array and you can not use array in that. So change the line as :

```
$data2 = array(
              'WZB_ProductCode'=>$this->input->post('productcode'),
              'ProductGrade'=>$this->input->post('productgrade'),
              'WZB_ProductName'=>$this->input->post('productname'),
              'WZB_ProductDescription'=>$datatiny['content'],
              'WZB_QuantityPerUnit'=>$this->input->post('quantityperunity'),
              'WZB_UnitPrice'=>$this->input->post('unitprice'),
              'WZB_ProductOwner'=>$this->input->post('productowner'),
              'WZB_CategoryName'=>$this->input->post('productcategory'),
              'WZB_VerifiedByAgent'=>$this->input->post('verifiedbyagent'),                  
              'ProductPhotoName'=>$imagesnames,
              'Addedby'=>$this->input->post('addedby')
            );
```

Comment: I have tried to add the data of the TinyMCE column as array below :

$content = $this->input->post('content');
$datatiny['content'] = $content;

Comment: @OlammieConcept you can not do this as array is not automatically converted to string.

Comment: @OlammieConcept You have to use json_encode($datatiny['content']) function for that or serialize($datatiny['content']) to convert array into json

Answer (score 0):

you have some mistake in code Either change this line

```
  $datatiny['content'] = $content;
```

to

```
  $datatiny = $content;
```

or change this array to

```
 $data2 = array(
          'WZB_ProductCode'=>$this->input->post('productcode'),
          'ProductGrade'=>$this->input->post('productgrade'),
          'WZB_ProductName'=>$this->input->post('productname'),
          'WZB_ProductDescription'=>$datatiny,
          'WZB_QuantityPerUnit'=>$this->input->post('quantityperunity'),
          'WZB_UnitPrice'=>$this->input->post('unitprice'),
          'WZB_ProductOwner'=>$this->input->post('productowner'),
          'WZB_CategoryName'=>$this->input->post('productcategory'),
          'WZB_VerifiedByAgent'=>$this->input->post('verifiedbyagent'),                  
          'ProductPhotoName'=>$imagesnames,
          'Addedby'=>$this->input->post('addedby')
        );
```

to

```
 $data2 = array(
          'WZB_ProductCode'=>$this->input->post('productcode'),
          'ProductGrade'=>$this->input->post('productgrade'),
          'WZB_ProductName'=>$this->input->post('productname'),
          'WZB_ProductDescription'=>$datatiny['content'],
          'WZB_QuantityPerUnit'=>$this->input->post('quantityperunity'),
          'WZB_UnitPrice'=>$this->input->post('unitprice'),
          'WZB_ProductOwner'=>$this->input->post('productowner'),
          'WZB_CategoryName'=>$this->input->post('productcategory'),
          'WZB_VerifiedByAgent'=>$this->input->post('verifiedbyagent'),                  
          'ProductPhotoName'=>$imagesnames,
          'Addedby'=>$this->input->post('addedby')
        );
```